# Play 2.3: Ebean Inheritance Single-Table with OneToOne field

Tags: java, inheritance, playframework, ebean, playframework-2.3

I have an abstract class to represent a type of settings. The inheritance type is in a single table as I wish to be able to access all types of settings irrespective of concrete type. Here is my parent abstract class:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public abstract class Settings extends Model {
   @Id
   public Long settingId;

   public static Model.Finder<Long, Settings> find = new Model.Finder<>(Long.class, Settings.class);

   public abstract void run();
}
```

This is one of my concrete types:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("text")
public class TextSettings extends Settings {

    public boolean type;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public EmailFields emailFields;

    public static Finder<Long, TextSettings> find = new Finder<>(Long.class, TextSettings.class);

    public static TextSettings get() {
        if (find.all().size() > 0)
            return find.all().get(0);
        else {
            TextSettings settings = new TextSettings();
            settings.emailFields = new EmailFields();
            settings.emailFields.test = "Test"; \\this field is null if you try to get this field with a get on the TextSettings ebean object
            settings.save();
            return settings;
        }
    }
}
```

This concrete type actually contains another ebean model with the `OneToOne` relationship. Here is the code for that model:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("email")
public class EmailFields extends Model {
   @Id
   public Long id;
   public String test;

   public static Finder<Long, EmailFields> find = new Finder<>(Long.class, EmailFields.class);
}
```

When I try to get the `EmailFields` model through the `TextSettings` model, I get the correct id and the object exists in the database, but the field `test` is null. Any field I add to it is always null.

This type of set up works for me in a non-inheritance ebean model so I can only think it has something to do with the single table. Does anyone know a solution for this, or will I have to copy the `test` field into the `TextSettings` model?

Note: I have simplified the code so logically it might not make sense as to why I have one field in `EmailFields` but the assumption is that I do need it as a separate model as some settings will have this model and some won't. So I don't want boilerplate code in those settings' classes.

**Update**
So for now I am using the `@Embedded` and `@Embeddable` annotations.

```
@Embeddable    
public class EmailFields extends Model
```

And in `TextSettings`

```
@Embedded
public EmailFields emailFields;
```

This simply copies `EmailFields`' fields into the `TextSettings` object and not as a separate entity. Only drawback with this is that it increases the size of the table.